# Angular: problem using code from one library in another library

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

Suppose an Angular workspace with two libraries inside (e.g. `projects/libA` and `projects/libB`). In `libA` I'm importing code from `libB`

```
import { ComponentX } from '@myscope/libB';
```

`ComponentX` is exported in `index.ts` located in `projects/libB/src`. In `tsconfig.json` (in root of worspace I have)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@myscope/libB": [
        "projects/libB/src"
      ]
    },
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  }
}
```

In `projects/libA/package.json` I have

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/libA",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@myscope/libB": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "sass": "./src/styles.scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Still while calling `ng build libA` I get many errors like

> The file <path_to_worspace>/projects/libB/src/.../component-x.ts is
> outside of the configured 'rootDir'.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you have the following project structure:

```bash
Workspace Root
│
├── tsconfig.json
│
├── projects
   │
   ├── libA
   │   ├── package.json
   │   └── ...
   │
   └── libB
       ├── src
       │   ├── index.ts (exports ComponentX)
       │   └── component-x.ts (contains ComponentX)
       └── ...
```

In that case, the Angular build system is checking the files being imported against the `rootDir` option in the `tsconfig.json` file. And since `libB` is outside of the `rootDir` of `libA`,... you get an error.

You can start with adjusting the `paths` option in the `tsconfig.json` to map `@myscope/libB` to `projects/libB/src/public-api`. Make sure `libB` has a `public-api.ts` file in its `src` directory that exports `ComponentX`.

```json
// tsconfig.json
"paths": {
  "@myscope/libB": [
    "projects/libB/src/public-api"
  ]
}
```

And:

```js
// projects/libB/src/public-api.ts
export * from './component-x/component-x.component';
```

Then make sure `libB` is built before `libA` using a script or, if using a compatible TypeScript version, set up project references in the `tsconfig.json`.

```bash
ng build libB && ng build libA
```

With:

```json
// tsconfig.json
"references": [
  { "path": "./projects/libB" },
  { "path": "./projects/libA" }
]
```

If necessary, adjust the `rootDir` compiler option to encompass both `libA` and `libB`.

```json
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  "rootDir": "./projects",
  ...
}
```

You would have:

```bash
Workspace Root
│
├── tsconfig.json (adjusted paths, references, and optionally rootDir)
│
├── projects
   │
   ├── libA
   │   ├── package.json
   │   └── ... (rest of libA files)
   │
   └── libB
       ├── src
       │   ├── public-api.ts (exports ComponentX)
       │   ├── component-x
       │   │   └── component-x.component.ts (contains ComponentX)
       │   └── ... (rest of libB files)
       └── ...
```

In `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./projects",  // Optional adjustment
    ...
  },
  "paths": {
    "@myscope/libB": ["projects/libB/src/public-api"]
  },
  "references": [  // If using project references
    { "path": "./projects/libB" },
    { "path": "./projects/libA" }
  ]
}
```

In `projects/libB/src/public-api.ts`:

```js
export * from './component-x/component-x.component';
```

Check then if `libA` is able to import `ComponentX` from `libB` without encountering the `'rootDir'` error, provided the build order is correctly managed (i.e., `libB` built before `libA`).

---

> Do I understand correctly that is I add `libB` to `peerDependencies` of `libA/package.json`, `libB` will not get bundled to `libA`?

Yes, that is correct.

When `libB` is listed in the [`peerDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) of `libA`, it signals that `libB` is a requirement for `libA`, but `libB` will not be bundled with `libA`.
Instead, it is expected that whoever is using `libA` will also install and provide `libB`. That is a common pattern for avoiding duplicate bundling of libraries, especially in scenarios where multiple [libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) are expected to interact with a shared instance of another library.

Comment: Thank you for very comprehensive answer! And do I understand correctly that is I add `libB` to `peerDependencies` of `libA/package.json`, `libB` will not get bundled to `libA`?

Comment: @Eugeny89 Yes. I have edited the answer to address your comment.